# How to Print data of one model in the view of another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

This is somewhat beginners question but unfortunately I am not able to figure out the solution hence asking at SO.

I have two models: `Name` and `NameProfile`.

`Name`: only `name` attribute

`NameProfile`: `name_id, email` attributes.

Now, I want to print `list of emails` in `/names/show.html.erb`

**NameController.rb**

```
def show
  @name = name.nameprofiles.email
end
```

**/views/names/show.html.erb**

```
<%= name.email %>
```

but I am getting undefined method error. Any Idea ?

Comment: Have you specified your relations in your models files ? `belongs_to` and `has_one` ?

Comment: and also post the error

Comment: @Pierre-OlivierBourgeois @PNY - Yes I have defined all the belongs_to and has_one relationship. The error is undefined local variable or method `name'

Comment: You defined an instance variable, call it with `@`: `<%= @name.email %>`

Comment: Can you post your `Name` and `NameProfile` models in your question?

Answer (score 0):

You want to do something like

```
class Name < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :nameProfiles
end

class NameProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :name
end
```

Then name.nameprofiles.email should work.  Check out http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html for more info.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that your `show action` is not doing is finding the particular `user`. You should refactor to something like this:

```
def show
      @name = Name.find(params[:id])
      @nameprofile = @name.nameprofiles
    end
```

Now you have a reference to your user as well its nameprofile association.

**In your views:**

```
<%= @nameprofile.email %>
```

This should be able to give you the user's email.